# Pull an element of an array according to one of the matches

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter, array-filter

I have two arrays:

```
$productIds = [
    ['product_id' => 12, 'price' => 1234],
    ['product_id' => 13, 'price' => 1235],
    ['product_id' => 14, 'price' => 1236]
];

$ids = [12, 14];
```

Then I iterate array `$ids` and must extract the array I need from the array `$productIds` by product ID:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $data[] = ... // get data by $id (equal 'product_id') from $productIds
}
```

At the output, I want to get such an array:

```
$data = [
    ['product_id' => 12, 'price' => 1234],
    ['product_id' => 14, 'price' => 1236]
];
```

But the solution must be without a nested cycle (foreach).

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
        $productIds = array_column($productIds,null,"product_id");
        $result = [];
        foreach($ids as $id){
            $result[] = $productIds[$id];
        }
```